# tableViewCells do not respond to didSelectRowAtIndex delegate when tableView is nested within another tableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection

Every time I make a tableview that contains another tableview/collectionView within one of it's cells, I am unable to get the UITableViewCells of the nested tableView to respond to the DidSelectRowAtIndex delegate meathods. I've tried various states of selections being enabled, etc with no luck. I notice that I can make selections with two fingers. Can anyone offer a solution?

Comment: WHY would you nest multiple tableviews? I can NOT and don´t want to believe that is the correct design decision.
And just to clarify: the method does not get called, or what? Have you set the delegate for both TableViews correctly?

Comment: I am sort of starting to believe the same thing, though I know people do this successfully from tim to time. http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2  I'd love to know the way others would solve these layouts I've been building.

Comment: I would highly suggest having a look at collection views. Or try to explain your situation briefly and clearly.

Comment: My table view has rows of cells with switches, a section with an email entry field plus a collection view to show and manage emails as they are entered. Below that is another table that shows a list of recent users. Other elements will be introduced dependent upon certain user settings. Many of these tables are reused independently in other controllers.
My alternative was to build this as a long UIScrollView, but I opted for the tableview structure mainly for the ease of controlling the vertically displayed content through a datasource.

Comment: I have set the delegates properly, all other delegate meathods are working. I can get the selection to work with two finger touch ion cells in nested tableviews.